# Is it possible to recreate VirtualDub Deshaker functionality in Adobe Premiere/After Effects?

Tags: software, virtualdub, premiere, after-effects

I'd like to automatically stabilize some poorly-shot shaky footage in Adobe Premiere or After Effects.

VirtualDub Deshaker analyzes frame motion, computes smoothing, adjusts frame position, scale and rotation, and does smart filling of the area outside a frame.

Is anything similarly powerful achievable using Adobe software, possibly via third-party plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Effects CS5.5 has the [Warp Stabilizer](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/after-effects-cs55-new-creative-techniques/ae-cs55-warp-stabilizer-instant-gratification/) (also check the video on the main [Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) site).

Answer (score 0):

Top menu>animation>stabilise motion
You'll have to find some tracking points, and if there's a lot of camera movement this is guaranteed to be a right royal PITA, but you don't need any 3rd party plug ins, because it's built in to after effects (since before it was even "CS", IIRC).

Alternatively you can use Mocha (or was that CS5?). It does a better job of stabilising footage, at the expense of a fairly unintuitive UI.

But what's wrong with Virtual Dub? Just because it's free doesn't mean it aint better.

Comment: Yep, it's a royal PITA up until CS5.5, when the Warp Stabilizer finally makes this a child's play! What's wrong with VirtualDub: nothing, it just doesn't exactly integrate into the editing workflow. You can use it to deshake one clip, but if you're editing a video composed of 50 clips, VirtualDub just doesn't cut it. (and I avoid intermediate renders like the plague)

Comment: Unless you know of a way to plonk a VirtualDub savefile right into the Premiere timeline, just like one can do with AE compositions? I'd love to be able to do that.

Comment: I thought I read that TOP was using CS4. Hmm.